# remove a style using jquery for a specific element

Tags: jquery, css

I need to remove the css style on this piece of code with Jquery.

`<div class="TabbedPanelsContent 1b"` `style="display: none;`">

and change it to css style

`<div class="TabbedPanelsContent 1b"` `style="display: block;`">

Can anyone help with the correct coding for this to work

Comment: `$('div').show();` would do the trick.  You can be more specific with the selector, of course, if there are more `div` elements on the page.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers

Comment: it would be helpful if I get a vote down to know how I can be clearer so as to ensure my next question is more easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using multiple class for an element, you can identify with the combination of those classes like below and change

```
 $(".TabbedPanelsContent.1b").css("display","block");
```

Simply call [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to Display or hide the matched elements.

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent.1b").toggle()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change css properties

```
$('.TabbedPanelsContent').css('display', 'block')
```

*OR*

You can use [**.show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to display it

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with

```
$('.TabbedPanelsContent.1b').css('display': 'block');
```

or

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent.1b").toggle();
```

If you want to consider only one of the class, just remove the other.
Pay attention that there's no space between the name of 1st class name and the dot of the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.TabbedPanelsContent').css('display', 'block');
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.TabbedPanelsContent').show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use like

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").show();
```

If you really want to use css,

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").css("disply","block");
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to avoid in line style tags where possible.
To replace this instead of the style tags you could use the jquery show / hide functions

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").show(); // behind the scenes sets display to block
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").hide(); // behind the scenes sets display to none
```

To answer your specific question you need removeAttr to remove it

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").removeAttr("style");
```

Or to just change it

```
$(".TabbedPanelsContent").attr("style","display:block"); // the value part of this may be off, but it's close
```